# cmake target_include_directories PUBLIC not working for object-library

Tags: cmake

lib1-CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib1_objs OBJECT
    hello.cpp
    hello.h
)
target_include_directories(lib1_objs
    PUBLIC ../third
)
add_library(lib1 STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1_objs>)
```

hello.h

```
#include<test.h> //Path: ../third/test.h
...
```

exe-CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(exe
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(exe
    PRIVATE lib1
)
target_include_directories(lib1_objs
    PRIVATE ../lib1
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "hello.h"
...
```

When I build 'exe', it would show an error

```
../lib1/hello.h:2 fatal error test.h No such file or directory
```

I already include '../third' directory PUBLIC in lib1-CMakeLists.txt. But it didn't propagate to exe-CMakeLists.txt. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which cmake version are you using? `../third` please try `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third`. Please add verbose build output (`cmake --build .. -v` or make VERBOSE=1).

Comment: @KamilCuk My cmake version is 3.17.3. I have tried '${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third', but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ach, you are doing `add_library(lib1 STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1_objs>)`, so you are just adding the object files, not including the library. You nowhere do `target_link_libraries(... lib1_objs)` and only `lib1_objs` knows about the include directory.

Comment: But lib1_objs just object, I want to link lib1 not lib1_objs. What should I do?

Comment: `lib1_objs just object` it's not "just" object, it's an object library, that also has an include directory that you added. If you want to link with `lib1`, why did you created `lib1_objs`? Remove it then and just `add_library(lib1 hello.cpp) target_include_direcotires(lib1 PUBLIC ../third)`. Also using `../` as directory paths is strange and confusing - prefer creating a clear out view of CMakeLists.txt that only use resources in the "current" tree they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just actually link with the object library:

lib1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(lib1 OBJECT
    hello.cpp
    hello.h
)
target_include_directories(lib1
    PUBLIC ../third
)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_executable(exe
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(exe
    PRIVATE lib1
)
```

`$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` are just object files - they do not know about include directories and such.

You could also:

lib1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(lib1_objs OBJECT
    hello.cpp
    hello.h
)
target_include_directories(lib1_objs
    PUBLIC ../third
)
    
add_library(lib1 STATIC) # I think it works, if not create an empty source file
target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC lib1_objs)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_executable(exe
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(exe
    PRIVATE lib1
)
```

but then `lib1_objs` could just be removed.